# Creating multiple unnamed pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe

I'm completely new to pipes, and I'm having trouble understanding something. I know to create a single pipe, it's simply

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
```

But what if I wanted to create a bunch of pipes? Would I use the same int array, or different ones? For example, if I wanted to create 3 pipes, would it be

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
pipe(fd);
pipe(fd);
```

Or

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
int fe[2];
pipe(fe);
int ff[2];
pipe(ff);
```

Comment: The first option leaks 4 pipes — you don't know what their file descriptors were after the third `pipe()` call succeeds.  You have only one usable pipe, though there are enough file descriptors for three open.  The second option is correct — you need a separate pair of file descriptors for each `pipe()` call, unless you have intervening `close()` calls between the invocations of `pipe()`, which the code shown does not.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to use different arrays. After calling `pipe(x)`, the file descriptors for the read and write ends of the pipe get put into the elements of `x`. If you call `pipe(x)` again, you will lose the file descriptors for the previously created pipe and won't be able to close it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple pipes and don't want to use multiple names for them, you can just use **2 dimensional array** like this:

```
int fd[3][2];

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   pipe(fd[i]);
}
```

This way you save the time and complexity of declaring multiple arrays